# How to find the index of a square matrix in Mathematica quickly?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix. The smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{k+1})=\mathrm{rank}(A^{k})$, is the *index* fo $A$ and denoted by $\mathrm{Ind}(A)$. I would like to compute $\mathrm{Ind}(A)$ quickly in Mathematica (I am using V8).

Let us as a very simple example consider

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$

then it is clear that $\mathrm{Ind}(A)=2$. For computing this in *Mathematica*, I used

```
Solve[MatrixRank[MatrixPower[A, k + 1]] == MatrixRank[MatrixPower[A, k]] && k > 0, 
   k, Integers]
```

But unfortunately, I cannot get the result. I will be grateful if anyone could design a way to compute $\mathrm{Ind}(A)$ for random matrices of the size $n\times n=200\times 200$ in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Hmmm, can't you just compute `MatrixRank[MatrixPower[A, k + 1]` for incresing `k` and just compare the previous two entries. Sorry don't have time for a full answer now...

Comment: In theory, one could look carefully at the Jordan block that goes with the eigenvalue of zero. In practice this will not scale very well, and the numeric methods involving `MatrixRank` in responses below should be better.

Comment: @Daniel That's correct. I implemented the Jordan block method (with `JordanDecomposition`): it processes a $200$ by $200$ floating matrix in under 0.1 seconds but the numerical error is apparent even in tiny matrices; just a little bit of error destroys the calculation of the index (all the eigenvalues become distinct under the tiny perturbations caused by FP arithmetic and the index always seems like it's equal to $1$). But why should `MatrixRank` perform any better with FP matrices? My experiments show it fails as badly, even on $3$ by $3$ matrices.

Comment: @whuber MatrixRank should use singular values under the hood if I am not mistaken. I think this would be fairly reliable. Can you post or send me the 3x3 where it fails?

Comment: @whuber (part 2) JordanDecomposition is not a good thing to try on non-exact input. I was never strongly in favor of extending it to approximate number input. To this day we find and fix bugs from that functionality. I'm not sure if we gained any advantage from having it.

Comment: @Daniel Let's create random $3$ by $3$ matrices of index $3$ and try. Most of the time this fails in that its output is not `{2,1,0}` (the correct answer found by removing the `N@` part): `n = 3;
p = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}];
q = Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 10^-3];
a = Inverse[q] . p . q;
MatrixRank[MatrixPower[N@a, #]] & /@ Range[Length@a]`. The reason for the failure should be clear. But once $n$ exceeds $10$ or so, the trouble gets much worse and patching it with `Chop` or whatever won't reliably work.

Comment: FWIW, the instability of computing the Jordan decomposition on inexact matrices is rather well-known (see e.g. Golub/Van Loan), which is why Schur is predominantly used in numerics.

Comment: @J. M. That's why I did not want to extend it to inexact input.

Comment: @whuber Okay, I think I see the issue. I'll post what might be a viable workaround.

Comment: Since it seems to have been ignored, let me repeat: Fazlollah, will you be computing the index for exact or inexact matrices?

Comment: Dear J.M., I must compute the index for both types of matrices. Specially for inexact matrices. It would also be nice if an algorithm could produce $k$, $A^k$ and $A^{k+1}$ at the end of its run for all types of matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The *idea* behind the Jordan normal form does the trick, even though `JordanDecomposition` does not.**  (Incidentally, this suggests there may be a more reliable, stable algorithm to obtain Jordan decompositions than is implemented in *Mathematica*...)  **The resulting solution is very short, efficient, and numerically stable** when applied to floating-point matrices.  The following begins with a brief explanation of how it works, followed by several examples to show it actually does work.

---

Let's consider how any matrix can have an index exceeding $1$. Because the rank of $A^2$ is less than that of $A$, the nullspace of $A$ must be non-trivial.  If the rank of $A^3$ further decreases, it must be because there is a sequence of vectors mapped by $A$, $v_2 \to v_1 \to 0$, with $v_1 \ne 0$.  *The index is the maximal length of such a sequence.*

This provides a numerically stable, relatively quick way to compute the index.  Beginning with computation of the nullspace $N_0$, find all vectors mapped by $A$ into the nullspace.  In other words, find a basis for the solutions to $A x \in N_0.$  As far as I can tell, *Mathematica* does not have a direct method to do this, so let's reduce it to one it does have.  `NullSpace` will provide a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ of $N_0$.  At the next step we seek a basis for the set of solutions

$$A x - \lambda_1 e_1 - \ldots - \lambda_k e_k = 0$$

This means the *augmented vector* $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n; -\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_k)$ lies in the nullspace of the matrix formed by augmenting $A$ with the columns $e_1, \ldots, e_k$.  Among the solutions of this equation will be the original nullspace.

Iterating this procedure creates a *flag* of vector spaces $N_0 \subset N_1 \subset \cdots \subset N_i = N_{i+1} = \cdots$; $i+1$ is then the index.  Provided we use a numerically stable procedure like `LinearSolve` or `NullSpace`, we can expect this algorithm to work even for large floating-point matrices.  First I will provide an implementation and then illustrate it with several examples.

To help us study what's going on, this version returns a "generalized index" consisting of a sequence of bases of the flag: it gives far more information about the structure of $A$ than just its index, but obviously its index is easily derivable from the output: it is just its length.  You should be able to recognize the iteration in `NestWhileList`, the augmentation of $A$ via `Join`, and the computation of nullspaces with `NullSpace` (including the initial nullspace, which is why this command appears twice).

```
index[a_] := 
With[{k = NullSpace[a]},
  If[k == {}, {}, 
   NestWhileList[
    NullSpace[Join[a, Transpose[#[[All, 1 ;; Length@a]]], 2]] &, k, 
    Length[#1] != Length[#2] &, 2, Length@a, -1]]];
```

The test for termination is when the dimensions of the solutions stabilize (as computed by applying `Length` to their bases).  Because termination occurs when $\dim(N_i) = \dim(N_{i+1})$, the final `-1` in the `NestWhileList` command throws away the superfluous basis for $N_{i+1}$.

(**Edit** A special test has to be made for nonsingular matrices, for then `Transpose` fails when the nullspace is empty.)

---

**To test this solution on large-ish matrices,** let's generate some with known indexes.  A good way to do this is to start with a bunch of Jordan blocks of zero eigenvalue: the index is one more than the longest contiguous string of superdiagonal ones (as is easily checked). Conjugating this by some random matrix (which is almost surely invertible) creates a non-sparse matrix for testing.

```
n = 30;
p = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}];
j = Floor[n/3]; p[[j, j + 1]] = 0;
q = Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 10^-2];
a = Inverse[q] .p . q;
ArrayPlot[p]
```

[image: Array plot]

*This is a plot of the Jordan normal form of $a$.*

A direct calculation of its index will determine the ranks of the matrix powers. Because this matrix is designed to have an index of $20$, we can hard-code this into the check:

```
(ranks = MatrixRank[MatrixPower[a, #]] & /@ Range[20] ) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\{7.1404084,\{28,26,24,22,20,18,16,14,12,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0\}\}$

After seven seconds, we find that indeed the index is exactly $20$: $A^{19} \ne 0$ but $A^{20} = A^{21} = \cdots = 0$.

Of course, the corresponding numerical (floating point) calculation is far faster--but it gets the wrong answer:

```
(nRanks = MatrixRank[MatrixPower[N@a, #]] & /@ Range[Length@a] ) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\{0.0100006,\{28,26,24,22,20,18,16,14,12,11,9,9,8,7,7,8,8,8,7,30,28,30,28,30,28,30,28,30,28,30\}\}$

Problems crop up around the $12^\text{th}$ power.  This is evident in a plot of the two tests:

```
ListPlot[{ranks, nRanks}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015], AxesLabel -> {"Power", "Rank"}]
```

[image: Plot of ranks]

Clearly the numerical calculations are producing garbage well before the correct index is reached.

I don't dare apply `index` to `a` itself: when using exact arithmetic, it's too slow! But let's see how it performs on the floating point version of `a`:

```
n = index[N@a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\{0.0100006,\text{Null}\}$

It's as fast as the numerical brute-force rank-of-matrix-powers solution was. What about accuracy?

```
Length@n
```

> $20$

It gets the right answer!  But perhaps this was only luck?  Let's check by restricting $A$ to the flag returned by `index`:

```
n0 = Reverse@(Last@n)[[All, 1 ;; Length[a]]];
u = Transpose[PseudoInverse[n0]] . a. Transpose[n0];
```

$u$ is just $A$ restricted to $N_{20}$, expressed in a different basis.  Here are portraits of its powers through the $20^\text{th}$:

```
GraphicsGrid[{(MatrixPower[u, #]//Chop//ArrayPlot) & /@ Range@Length@n}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Powers]

Up until the very end, the powers are nonzero, then finally the $20^\text{th}$ power is the zero matrix: this demonstrates the index of $A$ was *at least* $20$.

As another example, set $n=120$ in the previous one.  My trials produce the generalized index (that is, the entire flag of $80$ subvectorspaces) in one-half to one second and consistently calculate the correct index of $80$.  (I haven't tested with $n$ any larger than $120$ because it starts taking a long time just to create $a$.)

---

Finally, **let's apply this solution to the matrix of the question:**

```
a = {{1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0}, 
     {-1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 2}};
MatrixForm /@ index[a]
```

> $$\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$$

The first element of the list is a basis of the nullspace of $A$, which is one-dimensional.  The second element is a basis of the nullspace of an augmented version of $A$.  We are interested only in the first six entries in each row.  They form a basis for $N_1$.  They include (at the bottom) the previous basis for $N_0$.  As one last check, let's verify that $A$ sends the second basis into the span of the first:

```
a . Transpose@(Last@index[a])[[All, 1 ;; 6]] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Sure enough, the second basis vector is killed (it was in the nullspace) and the first is sent to a multiple ($-2$) of the second.  This detailed additional information about precisely how $A$ achieves its index is potentially useful in applications.

Comment: Overkill for the problem at hand but as the first to upvote this I will say it has an aesthetic appeal as well as independent interest. Could perhaps be adapted to a Jordan decomposition algorithm, for example, since finding those nontrivial block eigenspaces is the hard part.

Comment: Excellent idea. Can you check that why your technique cannot produce the result for a simple matrix in floating points arithmetic as follows: $n=100; a = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}]$. I faced with some errors such as "Transpose::nmtx: "The first two levels of the one-dimensional list {} cannot be transposed."".

Comment: Thanks: I tacitly assumed $A$ is singular; if not, the index is $0$.  I will add a test for this. However, the expression `RandomReal[,n,n]` is not even syntactically correct. The message you got indicates you created a vector rather than a matrix. An expression that will give you an actual $n$ by $n$ matrix would be `RandomReal[{0,1},{n,n}]`. For almost all such random matrices the index is $0$, so they don't make a very good test. Besides, you don't know in advance what the index is! Test instead with the code I provide, which produces *exact* matrices of *known* index.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Length@NestWhileList[A.# &, A, MatrixRank[#] != MatrixRank[#2] &, 2] - 1
```

This'll keep multiplying $A$ together and checking the matrix rank at each step.

Comment: `f@x` is a shorthand for `f[x]` and `#` and `&` are used in writing [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).  The rest should be easy to find in the documentation.

Comment: Since `MatrixRank` is relatively costly (compared to `Dot`) this could be improved by caching the rank of of the matrix between steps.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, there's often a tradeoff between simplicity and performance.  Why don't you post the faster solution?

Comment: @Szabolcs try testing your code with `A={{1, 1, -1, 2}, {-1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 2}, {1, 2, -1, 0}}`. In my machine the kernel keeps on running....

Comment: I think the code is not working well, Mr. Wizard is right down here. For a random matrix, it sould give 0 while produces 5 as the $Ind(A)$.

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani Fixed now. Not enough morning coffee apparently.

Comment: @Fazlollah, you should certainly check first if your matrix is singular before trying to compute the index...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the bad type of example mentioned in comments by @whuber.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 3; p = 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}]; q = 
 Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 10^-3]; a = Inverse[q].p.q;
na = N[a];
```

Badiosity check:

```
MatrixRank[MatrixPower[na, #]] & /@ Range[Length@na]

(* Out[318]= {2, 1, 3} *)
```

To see the source of trouble we'll have a look at singular values.

```
svlist = 
 Map[SingularValueList[#, Tolerance -> 10^(-6)] &, 
  FoldList[Dot, na, Table[na, {n - 1}]]]

9* Out[319]= {{13.1845622926, 
  1.63446803072}, {21.5497455662}, {2.03322204001*10^-14, 
  2.76424896137*10^-15, 1.86215833311*10^-16}} *)
```

Notice that the tolerance setting does nothing for that last list (in this example it does nothing for the others either, but that need not be the case in general). The reason is that all of them are small, and none are a factor of 10^6 or more smaller than the largest.

What we want in this situation is to have also an absolute threshold for removing them, as `Tolerance` only uses a relative threshold. `Chop` can do this. I will illustrate with a larger example.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 100;
p = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}]; q = 
 Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], 10^-3]; a = Inverse[q].p.q;
na = N[a];

Timing[
 svlist = Map[SingularValueList[#, Tolerance -> 10^(-6)] &, 
    FoldList[Dot, na, Table[na, {n - 1}]]];]

(* Out[340]= {0.180000, Null} *)

Map[Length, Chop[svlist, 10^(-6)] /. 0 :> Sequence[]]

(* Out[341]= {99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, \
85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, \
68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, \
51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, \
34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, \
17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0} *)
```

The upshot is you might want to experiment with setting `Tolerance`, and postprocessing using `Chop`, on `SingularValueList[]` of these powers.

Answer (score 4):

In version 13.0.1, there is an undocumented function `` LinearAlgebra`MatrixIndex ``. But I'm not sure when this was introduced

```
A={{1,-1,0,0,0,0},{-1,1,0,0,0,0},{-1,-1,1,-1,0,0},{-1,-1,-1,1,0,0},
   {-1,-1,-1,0,2,-1},{-1,-1,0,-1,-1,2}};

LinearAlgebra`MatrixIndex[A]
```

> `2`

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer OP's question, because ``LinearAlgebra`MatrixIndex[A]`` isn't in _v8_ :) . Not sure when this is introduced.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your kind reminder

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is correct but I'm running out of time to check it or develop it further.  I believe Szabolcs intented to write `!=` where he wrote `==`, but there is still the matter from starting with power zero.

Update #3:

```
f1 = {#, MatrixRank@#} &;
f2[m_][{_, {a2_, r2_}, n_}] := {{a2, r2}, f1[m.a2], n + 1}
f3[m_] := NestWhile[f2[m], {{-1, -1}, f1 @ MatrixPower[m, 0], -1}, #[[1, 2]] != #[[2, 2]] &]
```

Use:

```
A = {{1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0},
     {-1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 2}};

f3[A]
```

Output is in the form: {{matrix1, rank1}, {matrix2, rank2}, power}
You can use `Part` to extract whatever you need.

Comment: I think Mr. Wizard answer needs some revision. I mean the answers are not the same. For instance, check the following sample examples: Clear["Global`*"] SeedRandom[1234]; n = 500; A = RandomReal[{}, {n, n}]; Length@NestWhileList[A.# &, A, MatrixRank[#] == MatrixRank[#2] &, 2] // AbsoluteTiming Length@NestWhileList[{A.#[[1]], MatrixRank@#[[1]]} &, {A, -1}, #[[2]] == #2[[2]] &, 2] // AbsoluteTiming

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani Sorry, let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani I don't know that I understand the question.  Can you confirm that the output of Szabolcs's code is in fact the result that you want?

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani please take for example `SeedRandom[12345]; A = RandomReal[{}, {500, 500}];` then `Table[MatrixRank[MatrixPower[A, i]], {i, 0, 5}]` is `{500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 494}` -- wouldn't the *index* be either zero or one?  Szabolcs's code yields five.

Comment: Yes, your answer always gives 2 as the output by varying $n$, while the output of Szabolcs's code is correct and is what I want. Your technique to accelerate the process is nice, but currently not working.

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani I think my updated answer now agrees with the first one, but I still don't think I understand the question.  If the Rank of both A^1 and A^2 is 500, why isn't the answer one?

Comment: You are totally right Mr. Wizard, the codes sounds to be incorrect. For the 500*500 example of you, the answer must be $Ind(A)=0$. Because $A^0$ and $A^1$ agrees in terms of rank. So is there any bug here?

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani I made a revision to my answer.  I hope it is correct, but if not I don't have time to fix it again today.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wizard. It works good. Any improvement on the code will be appreciated.

Comment: Mr. Wizard, can you revise your code in order to give $A^k$ and $A^{k+1}$ as well. I mean I also need the last two matrices $A^{k+1}$ and $A^{k}$! Although $k$ is obvious but I do not want to compute them again because it might be time-consuming for large matrices! Can you give me a hand in this?

Comment: @FazlollahSoleymani I updated my answer.  I didn't have time to test its performance.  I hope it is of use to you.

Comment: You might consider having your routine terminate early if you find that `MatrixRank[m] == Length[m]`, where `m` is the starting matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I meant if for example the rank is 2, then I need $A^2$ and $A^3$, i.e. the last two matrices in process of computations not the first two matrices.

Answer (score 2):

We can exploit the fact that one can compute the index of a matrix from its minimal polynomial, so a good method is contingent on finding an efficient method for generating a matrix's minimal polynomial. Here, I present a not too fast method, but this can be sped up with a better algorithm for the minimal polynomial (e.g. by computing it directly from `JordanDecomposition[]`):

```
MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_?MatrixQ, x_] := Module[{qu, a0, mnm},
          a0 = IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]; mnm = {Flatten[a0]};
          While[Length[qu] == 0,
                a0 = a0.a;
                AppendTo[mnm, Flatten[a0]];
                qu = NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]]];
          Fold[(#1 x + #2) &, 0, Reverse[First[qu]]]]

MatrixIndex[a_?MatrixQ] /; TrueQ[Det[a] != 0] := 0;
MatrixIndex[a_?MatrixQ] := First[Cases[FactorSquareFreeList[
      MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a, \[FormalX]]], {\[FormalX], k_Integer} :> k]]
```

Using OP's example:

```
MatrixIndex[{{1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0},
             {-1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 2}}]
   2
```