# How to implement Drazin inverse?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Wolfram site [says](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DrazinInverse.html) it will be implemented in the future as `DrazinInverse[m]` function. But what to do *now*?

Comment: [There's a paper here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437950600512X?via%3Dihub) that has Mathematica code, although I don't understand enough of it. I tried implementing it and I'm not sure what to do with the results: `Return[{k, t, Expand[at], Expand[Btm2]}];`

Comment: @flinty it is behind paywall.

Comment: That's odd, I can see it perfectly fine - here's a pastebin of the code  https://pastebin.com/fbXn7YZA

Comment: See also [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29048) on scicomp stackexchange for other leads.

Comment: @flinty thanks. I tried the code on a 2x2 matrix but it does not return a matrix...

Comment: If $X$ is a solution to $A^{k+1} X = A^k$, $k$ being the index of $A$, then the Drazin inverse of $A$ is $A^k X^{k+1}$. This was first proved in my Ph.D thesis of 1975 and is also stated in Meyers and Campbell's book on Generalized Inverses.

Comment: For the index mentioned in @James's comment, see [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23955).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**
This is now possible in v13.0 with [`DrazinInverse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DrazinInverse.html)

---

Here's a better way to solve it I think. This avoids a lot of the issues in the `FindInstance` / `NMinimize` calculation I did earlier, and it's much more efficient:

```
DrazinInverse[A_] := 
 Module[{k = 0, Ak = IdentityMatrix@First@Dimensions@A, X, nxtA},
  While[nxtA = Ak . A; MatrixRank[Ak] != MatrixRank[nxtA],
   Ak = nxtA; ++k
  ];
  X = LinearSolve[nxtA, Ak];
  {Ak . MatrixPower[X, k + 1], k}
 ]

(* Check it works *)
test = {{2, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}};
{drzA, dk} = DrazinInverse[{{2, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}}]

(** {{{1/2, 0, 0}, {-(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 2} **)

First@DrazinInverse[{{3, .5}, {6, 1}}]
(** {{0.1875, 0.03125}, {0.375, 0.0625}} **)
```

---

I don't know enough about it to follow the papers in the comments, but you could use `FindInstance` or `NMinimize` to search for exact or approximate Drazin inverses that fit the definition:

```
DrazinInverse[A_] :=
 Module[{sol, Ad = Array[a, Dimensions[A]]},
  sol = FindInstance[
    MatrixPower[A, k + 1] . Ad == MatrixPower[A, k]
     && Ad . A . Ad == Ad
     && A . Ad == Ad . A,
    Flatten[{k, Ad}]
    ];
  If[sol == {}, Throw["Failed to find an inverse"], Ad /. First[sol]]
  ]

DrazinInverseApprox[A_] :=
 Module[{err, sol, Ad = Array[a, Dimensions[A]], cost},
  cost[X_, Y_] := Total[(X - Y)^2, 2];
  {err, sol} = NMinimize[{
     cost[MatrixPower[A, Round[k] + 1] . Ad, 
       MatrixPower[A, Round[k]]] +
      cost[Ad . A . Ad, Ad] +
      cost[A . Ad, Ad . A], k >= 1/2},
    Flatten[{k, Ad}], Method -> "RandomSearch"
    ];
  drzn::higherror = 
   "An error of `1` is high. Possibly inaccurate result";
  If[err > 10^-16, Message[drzn::higherror, err],
   Ad /. Chop[sol]
   ]
  ]
```

For example:

```
DrazinInverse[{{2, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}}]
(** {{1/2, 0, 0}, {-(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} **)
```

Sometimes this will fail with inexact matrices, in which case either `Rationalize` the matrix or use the approximate version:

```
DrazinInverseApprox[{{3, .5}, {6, 1}}]
(** {{0.1875, 0.03125}, {0.375, 0.0625}} **)
```